# Downloading a File with Python Or Wget with authentication

Tags: python, windows, hyperlink, beautifulsoup, wget

So basically I have tried numerous methods to download this file. I have both Python
and wget implementations. And really at this point could care less which one I can get to work.

Both do the same exact thing... They download the webpage, not the file I'm trying to download. Yet when I post the exact url provided into firefox, it immediately prompts me to download it.

What needs to happen:
1. connect to website (even though ssl is messed up on it?)
2. Authenticate myself
3. click the first link, which redirects to a download file
4. Download that file

First up my python code:

```
import httplib2
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

http = httplib2.Http()
http.add_credentials('username', 'password')
status, response = http.request('https://traveler.pha.phila.gov:8443/servlet/traveler')

counter = 0
Androidlink = ''
Windowslink = ''
Iphonelink = ''

for link in BeautifulSoup(response, parseOnlyThese=SoupStrainer('a')):
    if link.has_key('href'):         
        if counter == 2:
            Iphonelink = link['href']
            counter = counter + 1
        if counter == 1:
            Windowslink = link['href']
            counter = counter + 1   
        if counter == 0:
            Androidlink = link['href']
            counter = counter + 1


url = 'https://traveler.pha.phila.gov:8443' + Androidlink
print url


import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
r = requests.get(url,verify=False, auth=HTTPDigestAuth('username', 'password'))
print len(r.content)
```

Second, My Wget Code, just download the html of the website. Aka not what i want

```
wget --no-check-certificate "https://traveler.pha.phila.gov:8443/servlet/traveler?action=GET&deviceType=700&address=https%3A%2F%2Ftraveler.pha.phila.gov%3A8443%2Fservlet%2Ftraveler&userId=desantj&redirectURL=%2Ftraveler%2FLotusTraveler%2Fandroid%2FLotusTraveler.apk" --http-user=username --http-passwd=password
```

If i can get either of them to retreive this file (APK File), I'd be overjoyed as I have easily wasted over 6 hours grinding on this

*Note* Username and passwords were concealed for security reasons

Answer (score 1):

check 
    wget -O LotusTraveler.apk "https://traveler.pha.phila.gov:8443/servlet/traveler?action=GET&deviceType=700&address=https%3A%2F%2Ftraveler.pha.phila.gov%3A8443%2Fservlet%2Ftraveler&userId=desantj&redirectURL=%2Ftraveler%2FLotusTraveler%2Fandroid%2FLotusTraveler.apk" --http-user=username --http-passwd=password

**edit: sorry, i should have read better. so sorry again.. Although it doesn't the question why, i did find (with google) numerous download locations for similar/same files